# Does a repeated seasonal filter remove a polynomial trend

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

We define a polynomial trend model as
\begin{align}
X_t = a_n t^n + \ldots + a_1 t + a_0 + Z_t = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j t^j + Z_t, \qquad (*)
\end{align}
for a strictly stationary time series $Z_t$. We define the seasonal difference filter as
\begin{align}
\nabla_k\ X_t = X_t - X_{t-k},
\end{align}
where $k$ is the length of the season or period. *Now, I am wondering if a (repeated) seasonal filter will remove a polynomial trend*, i.e. $X_t$ becomes a stationary process.

In order to make this question more specific, it could be shown that 
\begin{align}
\nabla_k^n\ X_t = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}(-1)^i\ X_{t-ik}.
\end{align}
And implementing $(*)$ in the above expression yields
\begin{align}
\nabla_k^n\ X_t &= \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}(-1)^i \sum_{j=0}^n a_j (t-ik)^j + Z_{t-ik} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}(-1)^i \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \sum_{l=0}^j {j \choose l} t^j (-ik)^{j-l} + Z_{t-ik}.
\end{align}
For $n=1$ the statement holds, for $k=1$ $X_t$ becomes stationary.

To continue the proof by induction, for $n=m$ we assume that $X_t$ could become stationary for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, for $n = m+1$, how to find back the expression of $n=m$ in
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{m+1} {m+1 \choose i}(-1)^i \sum_{j=0}^{m+1} a_j \sum_{l=0}^j {j \choose l} t^j (-ik)^{j-l} + Z_{t-ik}\ ?
\end{align}
I am aware of the fact that the sums could be elaborated in terms of $1\leq i \leq m$ and $m+1$ and that
\begin{align}
{m+1 \choose i} = \frac{m+1}{m+1-i} {m \choose i}.
\end{align}
However, I do not see how to conclude the proof. Is there any other approach to prove this statement?